# Androidプログラミング(Rを変数に解決できません)

Tags: android

eclipse(Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2))でAndroidアプリを作っています。
一度はビルド＆動作していたのですが、色々とソースコードを変更したところ、あるときから「Rを変数に解決できません」とのエラーが出るようになりました。
Googleで調べてみると
1. import android.R;が存在する
　→存在しません。
2. res/layout/activity_main.xmlの確認
　→存在しますし、activity_main.xmlで画面を作っています。

今まで動いていたのに急にこのようなエラーが出て困り果てています。何をしたのか・・・。
解決方法ご存知であればご教示お願いします。

[image: エラー画面]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

クリーンプロジェクトはもう行いましたか？

Comment: クリーンプロジェクトはもう何度も行いました。

Comment: クリーンプロジェクトだけではエラー箇所の表示は直らなく、[プロジェクト]->[すべてビルド]でエラーが消えました。ビルドしなければいけなかったのですね。

Answer (score 1):

編集したxmlファイルのどれかにエラーがあると思われます。
レイアウトxml以外も確認してみてください。

Comment: レイアウトxml(AndroidManifest.xml)以外見当たらず・・・です。
http://php6.jp/android/2012/10/19/%E3%80%8Cr%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AB%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AE%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/
の記事を見つけました。
>解決方法ですが、Manifest.xml以外のxmlファイルのエラーを取り除き
>、保存します。
と同じことを言われてるようですが、以外のxmlファイルというのが見つかりません。そんなに複雑なプロジェクトを作っているわけではないのですが、お心当たりありますか？